# Send a string to specific number

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have a login page in which the user enters his iPhone number.
I want to send a string to that number, that the user will have to enter at the next page.
I can send it via SMS, but I wonder - if I'll send it via push notification, the user would be able to press the string from the notification, and won't have to enter it manually.

So, is it possible to send it via push notification? 
Is it makes sense?

Comment: Push notification is not guaranteed to be delivered.

Comment: what does that prove? or what is that 'string' used for? is this in an app or a web page?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can do it. But what if notificaion fails. we can not rely on notificaions. Use both sms and notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to verify the Phone number, Push Notification will not help you. You can send the deeplink (App Scheme URL with String Code), On click on link on the SMS will open the APP, By handling the deeplink you can access that string and automatically fill that string.

Please find below link for App Scheme URL
[http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible that u can send your **string** or **verification code** on that mobile no. But its will take time to sending using push notification.

Its not giving us to guarantee that its send/delivered successfully or not. Sometimes its not sended to user or sometimes its delay. So its better to send that string to user using bulk sms or as message. Its better to use both things to integrated into app.

**Note :** Bulk sms or message will inform us that message sending success or failed.